# Unable to check if there is conflict in date time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, time, conflict

I have a rails app that makes reservation by hour. I want to check for time conflict before booking.

DB

```
create_table :bookings do |t|
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :service, foreign_key: true
  t.datetime :booking_time
  t.datetime :booking_end

  t.integer :duration,  limit: 4
  t.integer :price
  t.integer :total
  t.boolean :status
  t.string :location, limit: 255
```

In the controller

```
def create
    booking_time = Date.parse(params[:booking_time])
    duration = params[:duration]
    booking_params[:booking_end] = booking_time + duration.hour
    @booking = current_user.bookings.create(booking_params) end
private
    def is_conflict(booking_time, new_booking_end)
service = Service.find(params[:service_id])
check1 = service.bookings.where(" ? >= booking_time AND ? <= booking_end", booking_time, booking_time)
check2 = service.bookings.where(" ? >= booking_time AND ? <= booking_end", new_booking_end, new_booking_end)

check1.size > 0 || check2.size > 0
```

end

In the view I have HTML and DATE/TIME picker and ajax to show the booking btn if there is no conflict otherwise show the date is not available.
the view:

```
<label>Day</label>
    <%= f.text_field :booking_time, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'start date', class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Time</label>
    <%= f.text_field :booking_time, readonly: 'true', class: 'timepicker' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for=" check out "></label>
    <%= f.select :duration, [["1",1], ["2",2], ["3",3], ["4",4]], prompt: "Duration...", readonly: 'true', class: "form-control" %>
```

and the Ajax function:

```
var input = {
                    'booking_time': booking_time,
                        'duration': duration,
                        'service_id': <%= @service.id %>,
                    };



                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/preview",
                        data: input,
                        success: function(data) {

                            if (data.conflict) {

                                $('#message').text("This date range is not available.");
                                $('#preview').hide();
                                $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', true);

                            } else {

                                $('#preview').show();
                                $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', false);

                                var total = duration * <%= @service.price %>
                                $('#booking_hours').text(duration);
                                $('#booking_sum').text(total);
                                $('#booking_total').val(total);
                            }
```

When I try to use it i got this error [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82TRT.png)

and when I delete the 3 lines at the first of def (create) it works but it won't store the booking end time in DB.

Any suggestions 
Thanks

Comment: You're Ajax request seems to be calling a different action. So you haven't shown the `preview` action or the code where the `create` action is called?

Comment: Here is the preview action : inline `def preview
  booking_time = Date.parse(params[:booking_time])
  duration = params[:duration].to_f
  new_booking_end = booking_time + duration.hour
  output = {
   conflict: is_conflict(booking_time, new_booking_end)
  }
  render json: output
 end`

Comment: Where are you calling `create`?

Comment: Do you mean `<%= form_for([@service, @service.bookings.new]) do |f| %>
` ? I have nothing more

Comment: I still can't see see enough of your code to be sure exactly what's happening here, but one thing to check is that you currently have have 2 `:text_fields` both named `:booking_time`. The second of these will be overriding the first one. So if a request is being made with the time field blank that would lead to the error you were seeing.

Comment: I see what you mean, Thank u Mike.